# Cannot parse String columns/data to Numeric while exporting Ag-Grid table to Excel using getDataAsExcel

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ag-grid, export-to-excel

I am trying to **export** data from an **ag-grid** table into excel using the API **getDataAsExcel**.

I have only one column which is supposed to have **string** values whereas all other columns are **numeric** and are displayed in my ag-grid table like **"6,999,500"**.

But when I try exporting it, all my columns have "**General**" or **String** format.

For example if my ag-grid looks like this:

**TABLE**

name | salary | fee

john | 10,000 |    14

dany |     50 | 1,000

where,
name -> string

salary -> numeric

fee -> numeric

It's weird that when I export this table into **excel**, all values are saved as "**String**" except 14 and 50 in this case.
I noticed the numbers which doesn't have a ',' **separator** (like 14, 50 here) are exported numeric and 10,000 and 1,000 (having **NO** ',' separator) are exported as **string**.

I used **parseInt**() function such as:

if value = 10,000

parseInt(value.replace(/,/g, ''));

I replaced 10,000 with its parsed value, but no luck since it still prints it as String.

How can I change the format of the complete column or atleast parse these values individually?

Any Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you have to define `dataType` [explicitly](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-excel/#defining-styles) for excel export.

```
var columnDef = {
    ...,
    cellClass: 'itsANumber'
};

ExcelStyles: [
        {
            id: "itsANumber",
            dataType: 'number', // can use string, number, boolean, dateTime
        },
```

> dataType (optional): One of (string, number, boolean, dateTime, error). In most cases this is not necessary since this value is guessed based in weather the cell content is numeric or not. This is helpful if you want to fix the type of the cell. ie. If your cell content is 003, this cell will be default be interpreted as numeric, and in Excel, it will show up as 3. But if you want to keep your original formatting, you can do so by setting this property to string.